# Show a Function is strictly monotone Increasing, and what does it say about its inverse?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

For example:

$$g(x)=x^3-3x^2-1 \quad, \quad x\in [2,+\infty]$$

What I have tried to do was to take the first Derivative. I get 
$$ g'(x)=3x^2-6x$$

I then check the sign of Derivative of g(x) at $x=2$: $$ 3x^2-6x \big|_{x=2} =0$$ So, this check always doesn't work? 
And if I show it is strictly monotone increasing, what does it say about it's inverse?

Comment: At $x=2$ the derivative is $0$, not less than $0$. For $x\gt 2$ it is $\gt 0$.

Comment: But when x=2.  $$3x^2-6x = 0$$   not > than.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $2\le a\lt b$. By the Mean Value Theorem, there is a $\xi$, with $a\lt \xi\lt b$ such that 
$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(\xi).$$ Since $\xi\gt 2$ we can conclude that $f'(\xi)\gt 0$, so $f(b)\gt f(a)$. The fact that the derivative **at** $2$  is $0$ is irrelevant, even for the case $a=2$. The function is strictly increasing in the interval $[2,\infty)$.